# How to get files off of Nexus 5 Android when LCD Screen + Touchscreen doesnt work?

Tags: adb, nexus-5, data-recovery, fastboot, broken-screen

So I have a Nexus 5 Android 32gb phone that boots up but the LCD screen and touchscreen doesnt work. I know because it gets detected on my computer. Also the bootloader is still locked, which means I cannot flash a recovery image to it. Also I do not have usb debugging on so I cannot connect via adb.

I have a bunch of family photos on the phone and would like to get these files off. What other alternatives can I do to get these files off?

I even changed the LCD screen and that doesnt work neither. It's possible that some chip on the motherboard is fried, but I'm not even sure how to test something like that. However I do have the proper tools for micro soldering, but not sure how to go about this.

Another option I was thinking about is extract the SD chip on the board and implant it to another nexus system. This requires extreme micro-soldering work and reballing. The sd chip that the nexus 5 uses is the following: SDIN8DE4-32G

Totally loss on what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ADB debugging turned on, you can give Vysor a try: http://www.vysor.io/

PS: If you can't get to it because the phone is locked, attach a computer keyboard to the phone and unlock it.

Comment: i do have a OTG usb plug. If i plug a keyboard into the phone. How do I go about navigating to the system menu if I cannot see anything?

Comment: That's the catch 22. What you could do is use the keyboard (or even a mouse if you have a pattern) and unlock the phone, then plug it into the computer to use Vysor.